# I have a table with data per month.How to average of data per quarter using select query from this table

Tags: sql

Below table shows data per month per year.I want to get average of value per months.

Sample data of my table:

```
month year value 
-----------------
01    2017  89
02    2017  09
03    2017  89
04    2017  22
```

Output should be

```
month year   output
-------------------------------
01    2017   89
02    2017   (89 + 09) / 2
03    2017   (89 + 09 + 89) / 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rolling average to get your desired output. I assumed that you are using SQL server.

```
with cte as 
( 
 select '01' as monthp, '2017' yeart, cast('89' as int) as valuen union all 
 select '02' as monthp, '2017' yeart, cast('09' as int) as valuen union all 
 select '03' as monthp, '2017' yeart, cast('89' as int) as valuen union all 
 select '04' as monthp, '2017' yeart, cast('22' as int) as valuen ) 

 select monthp, yeart, avg(valuen*1.0) over (order by monthp, yeart) outputsum   from cte
```

Output: Please note that I converted this value to decimal to get accurate value.

```
   monthp   yeart   outputsum
   01       2017    89.000000
   02       2017    49.000000
   03       2017    62.333333
   04       2017    52.250000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this!

```
 SELECT [Month], [Year], (CASE WHEN [Month] BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN AVG([Value]*1.0) 
 OVER (ORDER BY [Month], [Year]) WHEN [Month] BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN AVG([Value]*1.0) 
 OVER (ORDER BY [Month], [Year])WHEN [Month] BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN AVG([Value]*1.0) 
 OVER (ORDER BY [Month], [Year])WHEN [Month] BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN AVG([Value]*1.0) 
 OVER (ORDER BY [Month], [Year]) END) [Value]   
 FROM Table   //your table Name
```